# Concat two strings and print it on a label c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have several `radioButtons` stored in two different strings.
I need them printed bound together on a label. How can I do it?

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        String cad1 = null;
        String cad2 = null;

        if (rad1.IsChecked == true)
        {
            cad1 = "Ok";
        }
        else if (rad2.IsChecked == true)
        {
            cad1 = "Ok Cancel!";
        }
        else if (rad3.IsChecked == true)
        {
            cad1 = "Yes No";
        }
        else if (rad4.IsChecked == true)
        {
            cad1 = "Yes  No Cancel";
        }
        else if (rad5.IsChecked == true)
        {
            cad1 = "Retry Cancel";
        }
        else if (rad6.IsChecked == true)
        {
            cad1 = "Abort Retry Cancel";
        }
        else if (rad7.IsChecked == true)
        {
            cad2 = "Information";
        }
        else if (rad8.IsChecked == true)
        {
            cad2 = "Exclamation";
        }
        else if (rad9.IsChecked == true)
        {
            cad2 = "Question";
        }
        else if (rad10.IsChecked == true)
        {
            cad2 = "Error";
        }
```

I need to print the result of these two strings, but for the moment, the second string is not printed

```
        cad1 = cad1 + cad2;
        lab2.Content = cad1;

    }
}
```

Comment: There is never a case where you give a value to both `cad1` and `cad2`. Not ever. Always set a breakpoint and use the debugger to examine the values of the variables before making wild guesses about what happened.

Comment: Obviously cad2 is null in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is all of your cad2 variables are contained in else if statements.

Modify the line

```
else if (rad7.IsChecked == true)
```

to be

```
if (rad7.IsChecked == true)
```

**EDIT**
I would also recommend removing all `== true`, they are unnecessary.
If the `cad1` and `cad2` aren't being used after this event I'd recommend creating a single string variable and appending the values that would have been `cad1` and `cad2` to it.

```
var cont = "";  
if (rad1.IsChecked) cont += "Ok";  
...  
if (rad7.IsChecked) cad2 += "Information";  
...
lab2.Content = cont;
```

Answer (score 2):

Elsif only get s evaluated if the first if was not true, so if cad1 gets a value, cad2 never gets a value.

Furthermore, `if (rad9.IsChecked == true)` is exacttly the same as `if (rad9.IsChecked)'

And finally, if you're using an up-to-date version of C# you can use the ternaty operator:

```
var cad1 = rad1.IsChecked
           ? "Ok"
           : rad2.IsChecked 
             ? "Ok Cancel!"
             : rad3.IsChecked
               ? "Yes No"
               : rad4.IsChecked
                 ? "Yes  No Cancel"
                 : rad5.IsChecked
                   ? "Retry Cancel"
                   : rad6.IsChecked
                     ? "Abort Retry Cancel"
                     : null;
var cad2 = rad7.IsChecked
           ? "Information"
           : rad8.IsChecked
             ? "Exclamation"
             : rad9.IsChecked
               ? "Question"
               : rad10.IsChecked
                 ? "Error"
                 : null;
```

Or, if you like it more concise:

```
var cad1 = rad1.IsChecked ? "Ok"
         : rad2.IsChecked ? "Ok Cancel!"
         : rad3.IsChecked ? "Yes No"
         : rad4.IsChecked ? "Yes  No Cancel"
         : rad5.IsChecked ? "Retry Cancel"
         : rad6.IsChecked ? "Abort Retry Cancel"
         : null;
var cad2 = rad7.IsChecked ? "Information"
         : rad8.IsChecked ? "Exclamation"
         : rad9.IsChecked ? "Question"
         : rad10.IsChecked? "Error"
         : null;
```

Now, I wonder if rad1-10 are radiobuttons, and why I cannot see in the name which ones belong to the same group. I hope 1-6 are in one and 7-10 are in another group, but better naming would avoid confusion and possible mistakes...

Comment: You're right, but I'm learning, this is my third exercise. I've been in class for two weeks. the ternary operator seems difficult to start with :D

Answer (score 1):

In your if-else chain you never set values for both cad1 and cad2 so you never get the correct output.

Te easieset way to get what you want is to split the chain to look llike this

```
    ... 
    else if (rad6.IsChecked == true)
    {
        cad1 = "Abort Retry Cancel";
    }

    if (rad7.IsChecked == true)
    {
        cad2 = "Information";
    }
    ...
```

Comment: I tried it with @Tubs answer and it works perfectly for me, but its true,  if I initialize the two variables as null I may have problems. Thaks you :)